# Find what position number would go in a list of numbers, if it was part of that list

Tags: excel, vba

If I have a series of numbers in Excel e.g.

```
0
1
8
12
15
27
```

And I want to find out where the number 9 would fit in between all those numbers (position 4), how would I do this?

Comment: Use *Match()* ...........

Comment: You could avoid #NA() errors when entering a number that's less than the minimum in the list by using IFERROR.   `=IFERROR(MATCH(D4,$A$1:$A$6,1)+1,1)` no VBA required.

Answer (score 0):

use [Match()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835873.aspx) function, like

```
Dim pos as Variant 
pos = Application.Match(9, Range("A1:A10"), 1) + 1
```

since setting 3rd argument to `1` it *"finds the largest value that is less than or equal to lookup_value"*